# exc_bad_access when calling method swift on custom nsview class in OSX

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, nsview

This is a simple question but I can't figure it out.

I have a custom NSView inside an `NSWindowController` with the class named `MyView`:

```
import Cocoa

class MyView: NSView {

    func doNothing () {
        NSColor.green.set()
    }

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)


    }

}
```

In my NSWindowController (class named MainWindowController) I have
import Cocoa

```
class MainWindowController: NSWindowController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapaView: MyView!

    override var windowNibName: String {
        return "MainWindowController"
    }

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
        window?.contentAspectRatio = mapaView.frame.size
    }



    @IBAction func aver(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        mapaView.frame = CGRect(x: 10.0, y: 10.0, width: 30.0, height: 50.00)
        mapaView.doNothing()
    }
}
```

And an `NSButton` connected to the `IBAction aver()` in the `MainWindowController`

When I click on the button the frame in `mapaView` changes fine but the `mapaView.doNothing()` crashes with a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 2, address=0x7fff...)`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have probably some error with your outlet action, try to remove all actions from the button and recreate it again.

Comment: same error happens if I put the mapaView.doNothing() inside the windowDidLoad() function